# Get last word of string in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

In pure Mapinfo SQL Update code I need to extract the last word of a string.

Ex

- SUTHERLAND STREET
- BURKE DEVELOPMENTAL ROAD
- Street Not Specified

The following `Update DCDB_DNRME Set road_type = Mid$(road_name,(InStr(1,road_name," ")+1),len(road_name))` gives me

- STREET
- DEVELOPMENTAL ROAD
- Not Specified

I just need

- STREET
- ROAD
- Not Specified

Is there an equivalent to rfind in python?

Comment: Could you just run the same Update statement several times in a row? (would need to add in a `WHERE InStr(1,road_name," ") >0`).  Not pretty, but if it's just part a snippet of code you want to paste into the MapBasic window and run from time to time, it will do the job.

Comment: Yup -thanks. I have done this but still hoping that there's a right find.